# How to run a 'prog-mode-hook' after more specific hooks?

Tags: hooks, derived-mode

I'm running into an order of initialization issue with hooks.

- `prog-mode-hook` enables `fci-mode`
- `rust-mode-hook` sets the `fci-rule-column` to 99.
- on initial display the fill column shows at 80 (it's original value), moving the cursor redraws at 99.

This is not really a question about `fci-mode`, the solution is to set `fci-rule-column` before starting `fci-mode` (after or at the end of the `rust-mode-hook`).

To avoid needing to add generic code into all my programming mode hooks:

Is there a way to run a generic `prog-mode-hook` *after* more specialized hooks run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `after-change-major-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'my-after-change-major-mode-prog-mode)
(defun my-after-change-major-mode-prog-mode ()
  "Custom `after-change-major-mode-hook' behaviours."
  (when (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
    ...))
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380 for more details on the sequence of events when derived modes run.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
(defun my-prog-mode-hook ()
  (when (derived-mode-p 'rust-mode)
    (setq fci-rule-column 99))
  (fci-mode 1))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-prog-mode-hook)
```

Comment: This works too, I just wanted to keep all my rust options in one place instead of scattered all over the file.

Comment: Indeed, the best choice depends on whether you prefer to keep all your Rust settings in one place or if you prefer to keep all your fci settings in one place.